Angular Signals: api call without unsubscribe
I am confused whether it's possible to make api call onInit component and evry time when parent gets event from child (pagination component), call api with new pageSize and pageNumber and assign this data. Main problem is that i want to avoid manually unsubscribe, and effect (beacuse it's not recomended to use it to change state).Maybe at this time there is no other option that unsubscribe. My next question is, is it more recommended to use a model instead of input and output signals?
child component ts
  rows = input.required<number>();
  pageChanged = output<number>();
  onPageChange(event: PaginatorState) {
    this.pageChanged.emit(event.rows!);
  }

parent component html
<app-paginator
  [rows]="pageSize()"
  (pageChanged)="onPageChange($event)"
  [totalRecords]="dataResponse()?.totalElements || 0"
  [(paginationData)]="pagination"
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="allowedNumbersOfRecordOnOnePage"></app-paginator>

parent component ts
    pageNumber = signal<number>(0);
      pageSize = signal<number>(100);
    //apiService.getData(arg1,arg2) return observable
 dataResponse= toSignal(
    this.apiService.getData(this.pageNumber(), this.pageSize())
  );

  onPageChange(pageSize: number) {
    this.pageSize.set(pageSize);
// How to set data to dataResponse reactively to signal without manually unsubscribe?
    
  }


There are multiple ways to achieve it.
toObservable()
You can convert your signals to Observables using toObservable() (developer preview). Use combineLatest() to combine them and and switchMap() to trigger the API requests:
pageNumber = signal<number>(0);
pageSize = signal<number>(100);
data$ = combineLatest(
  toObservable(this.pageNumber),
  toObservable(this.pageSize)
).pipe(
  switchMap(([pageNumber, pageSize]) =>
    this.apiService.getData(pageNumber, pageSize)
  ),
);
dataResponse = toSignal(data$);

resource()
Since Angular 19 you can use the experimental resource() function which allows asynchronous handling with Signals. While the base resource() function only supports Promises, you can also use the rxResource() function which supports Observables:
import { rxResource } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

pageNumber = signal<number>(0);
pageSize = signal<number>(100);
dataResource = rxResource({
  request: () => ({
    pageNumber: this.pageNumber(),
    pageSize: this.pageSize(),
  }),
  loader: ({ request }) => {
    const { pageNumber, pageSize } = request;
    return this.apiService.getData(pageNumber, pageSize);
  },
});


You use models, when you need two way data binding, if it's one way data binding use input.
here model is better since you trigger the API when the child changes, also you need to update the child, when the parent updates the value.
<app-paginator
  [(rows)]="pageSize"
  (pageChanged)="onPageChange($event)"
  [totalRecords]="dataResponse()?.totalElements || 0"
  [(paginationData)]="pagination"
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="allowedNumbersOfRecordOnOnePage"></app-paginator>

Update the child to have a model.
rows = model<number>();

onPageChange(event: PaginatorState) {
  this.rows.set(event.rows!);
}

Now you can use computed to react to the changes. We also need to make sure pageSize is a model, so that the changes propagated by the child model, update the parent model.
pageNumber = signal<number>(0);
pageSize = model<number>(100);
//apiService.getData(arg1,arg2) return observable
dataResponse = computed(() => 
    this.apiService.getData(this.pageNumber(), this.pageSize()))();

onPageChange(pageSize: number) {
  this.pageSize.set(pageSize);
  // How to set data to dataResponse reactively to signal without manually unsubscribe?
}

Finally in the HTML, we use async pipe to get rid of the unsubscribe needed, which is taken care of by the async pipe.
{{dataResponse | async}}

Below is a working example simulating your scenario.
import {
  Component,
  computed,
  inject,
  Injectable,
  signal,
  model,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { toSignal } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {
  getData(pageNumber: number, pageSize: number) {
    const arr = new Array(11).fill({}).map((item: any) => {
      item.pageNumber = pageNumber;
      item.pageSize = pageSize;
      return item;
    });
    return of(arr);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="pageNumber">
  `,
})
export class Child {
  pageNumber = model<number>();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <app-child [(pageNumber)]="pageNumber"/>
    {{dataResponse() | async | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  apiService = inject(ApiService);
  pageNumber = model<number>(0);
  pageSize = signal<number>(100);
  //apiService.getData(arg1,arg2) return observable
  dataResponse = computed(() =>
    this.apiService.getData(this.pageNumber(), this.pageSize())
  );
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
